# An idempotent grammar for text decoding?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings

I'd like to create a function `decode(x : string)` such that `decode(x : string) == decode(decode(x : string))`.

I believe I can think of how to do this with reserve chars. Is that my only option?

I'm not much of a theory guy. But, I think essentially what I need to do is represent a structure that is idempotent on substitution (of a particular form) as a string. Does anyone know any good papers on doing something like this?

Comment: Another option that meets your requirements is the identity function.

Comment: @Steven Do you mean constructing the string such that its decoded form is somehow its identity? Do you have a practical example?

Comment: I just mean that `decode(x) = x` satisfies the constraints.

Comment: Yeah, but that expression means the function (if pure) does nothing useful.

Comment: Then to get a good answer you'll have to define what "useful" means to you in this context. What properties should the decode function have beside being idempotent?

Comment: How would a pure function `decode(x) = x` ever be useful? That's just `(x)->x`. For me, I need the function to to perform some kind of decoding, but once decoded further attempts to decode the output are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130333/discussion-between-lmonninger-and-steven).

Comment: Since you are talking about decoding, there should exist function `encode`. such that `decode(encode(x)) = x` for any `x`. Therefore, `decode(x) = decode(decode(encode(x))) = decode(encode(x)) = x`. I.e. identity is the only such function.

Comment: What data structures would you suggest looking into to meet this condition?